# AttributeError: module 'bcrypt' has no attribute 'hashpw' for python

Tags: python, bcrypt

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `bcrypt` is installed properly?

Comment: If you called a file `bcrypt.py`, call it something else.

Comment: Yea, it's not called bcrypt.py and I'm not exactly sure if it's installed because it's on pythonanywhere.com so I'm wondering if I have to install it myself or what.

Comment: You could check `help(bcrypt)` after the import because bcrypt import isn't throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

yes it really works when we change the name of file like bcrypt.py to any.py but not bcrypt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and went through these steps to figure it out:

`pip list` double check that bcrypt is in that list

`python --version` which returned Python 2.7.15rc1

`python3 --version` which returned Python 3.6.7

I had an issue where python3 doesn't recognize the bcrypt package:

```
    python
    Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
    [GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>>import bcrypt (pressed enter here)
    >>>
```

vs

```
    python3
    Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
    [GCC 8.2.0] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import bcrypt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bcrypt'
```

then when double checking my file listing ran into the same issue [@user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) suggested and renamed the "bcrypt.py" file I had created.

You stated that bcrypt.py is not the name of the file so I tried something else to recreate and built a new bcrypt.py file next to my pharaoh.py and reproduced the same error.

My code currently:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import bcrypt

    # raw_input for pv2
    user = raw_input("User value: \n")
    password = raw_input("password: \n")


    def pass_thru_crypt(user, password):
           user_password = user + password
           hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(user_password, bcrypt.gensalt())
           if bcrypt.checkpw(user_password, hashed):
               print("Indiana Jones just *bad_word* you up, Charlie!")
           else:
               print("You chose... poorly")

    pass_thru_crypt(user, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on my Ubuntu server. Installing these dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libffi-dev python-dev
```

worked for me. For your distro the dependencies might be different, look here: https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/