# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Django - module 'bcrypt' has no attribute 'checkpw'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, bcrypt

I am getting this error on my AWS Server

```
    if bcrypt.checkpw(password, usrPassword):

        Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/user/login/
        Exception Value: module 'bcrypt' has no attribute 'checkpw'
        Request information:
        USER: AnonymousUser
```

I installed the PIP Bcrypt Library

```
pip install bcrypt
```

But Still I am getting same error

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586448/attributeerror-module-bcrypt-has-no-attribute-hashpw-for-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: module 'bcrypt' has no attribute 'hashpw' for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586448/attributeerror-module-bcrypt-has-no-attribute-hashpw-for-python)

Comment: No, it's not working. I tried it, I checked those questions before posting this

Comment: `sudo apt-get install build-essential libffi-dev python-dev`

This got worked. Thank you everyone.